# Regex match specific string without other string

Tags: php, regex, match, except

So I've made this regex:

```
/(?!for )€([0-9]{0,2}(,)?([0-9]{0,2})?)/
```

to match only the first of the following two sentences:

1. discount of €50,20 on these items
2. This item on sale now for €30,20

As you might've noticed already, I'd like the amount in the 2nd sentence not to be matched because it's not the discount amount. But I'm quite unsure how to find this in regex because of all I could find offer options like:

```
(?!foo|bar)
```

This option, as can be seen in my example, does not seem to be the solution to my issue.

Example:
https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/y2D

Suggestions?

Comment: what exactly is your problem, it looks correct for me on https://regex101.com/r/uQmAH2/1 ?

Comment: You should definitely rephrase your question and include information about how exactly you differ discount and non-discount amounts (do they always come in a specific order,, are they always accompanied by a certain phrase...).

Comment: Updated with an example from php live regex: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/y2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<!\bfor\s)€(\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SB4vPF/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\bfor\s)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a whole word `for` and a whitespace immediately before the current position
- `€` - a euro sign
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a comma and one or more digits

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/2SEXG):

```php
$strs= ["discount of €50,20 on these items","This item on sale now for €30,20"];
foreach ($strs as $s){
    if (preg_match('~(?<!\bfor\s)€(\d+(?:,\d+)?)~', $s, $m)) {
        echo $m[1].PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "No match!";
    }
}
```

Output:

```php
50,20
No match!
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure to match the `discount` first in the line:

```
\bdiscount\h[^\r\n€]*\K€\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2})?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bdiscount\h` A word boundary, match discount and at least a single space
- `[^\r\n€]\K` Match 0+ times any char except € or a newline, then reset the match buffer
- `€\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2})?` Match €, 1-2 digits with an optional part matching `,` and 1-2 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BdYudF/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/uZngT)

```
$re = '/\bdiscount\h[^\r\n€]*\K€\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2})?\b/';
$str = 'discount of €50,20 on these items €
This item on sale now for €30,20';

if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
    echo($matches[0]);
}
```

Output

```
€50,20
```